# Basic Rewrite Rule condition don't work

Tags: .htaccess

I have been searching, but I can't find a solution.

I want that when I write in example:

```
http://www.example.com/hiddendirectory/7-content/
```

maps to

```
http://www.example.com/7-content/
```

I mean, delete hiddendirectory from the view of the user.

I had try this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^hiddendirectory /hiddendirectory%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```